# Eloquent relation clarification

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, eloquent

Following is my query

```
 $user = User::with(['session' => function ($query) {
            $query->select('id','device_id');
            $query->where('api_token', '=', '123456');
          }])->get();
```

session: `hasMany` relation with User.

I am expecting a user with a session having api_token = 123456. Instead I am getting whole users here. I know I am doing something wrong.

I am referring this [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads). In the doc it is saying that we can add constraint to the query. But here `$query->where('api_token', '=', '123456');` this where is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it worked.

```
 $sessionSelect =  function ($query) {
      return $query->select( 'user_id', 'device_id');
 };
 $detailSelect = function ($query) {
      return $query->select('user_id', 'dob', 'gender');
 };
 $sessionWhere = function ($query) use ($key) {
      return $query->where('api_token', $key);
 };
 $users = User::with(['session' => $sessionSelect,'detail'=>$detailSelect])
          ->whereHas('session', $sessionWhere)
          ->first();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not filtering the User, you are filtering the result of the eager loading of 'session'. Eager loading does not have any effect on the base result set in anyway.

It sounds like you want to filter User by the 'existence' of a relationship in the database.

```
User::whereHas('session', function ($q) { 
    $q->where('api_token', '12345');
})->get(); // ->first();
```

Get all Users that have a Session where 'api_token' == '12345'.

[Laravel 5.5 Docs - Eloquent - Relationships - Querying Relationship Existence](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

Comment: But how can I get the session details?  I tried this $q->select(['id','device_id']); not fetching session details

Comment: `whereHas` is not for fetching the record, it is for filtering based on existence of a relationship ... `with` eager loads, you have to select the keys used for the relationship ... if you dont it can't match the records back up to their parents